# Is it possible to use generic types with JHipster studio?

Tags: java, hibernate, jhipster, jdl

I am running a JHipster application, and I was wondering if I could use the JDL studio to design an entity with generic types.

Given the following entity class:

```
     @Entity
      public class Box<T>{

      @Any
      private T t;   

      @Id
      private long id;

       public void setT(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
    }
```

And mapping the following Entity as described in the JDL, what configuration can I use with Hibernate in such case?

Comment: In jhipster this is not handled yet afaik. You need to handle this by yourself (it may help here is the possible data types  https://jhipster.github.io/jdl/#annexes.)

Comment: Ok, that means I can't use the JDL studio to design it then, right?

Comment: Right you cannot.

Comment: Thanks @ismail. That could be something to deal with during the Hackathon in two weeks.

Comment: Another question @ismail: Is JDL studio extensible?